# Use xml_split to split an XML file based on a Perl regex or XPath expression

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I have a huge XML file that I want to split into chunks based on the product type attribute.

I don't know how to use XSLT. I found [`xml_split`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.49/tools/xml_split/xml_split) but can't figure out how to use it with a regex or XPath to split the document depending on the type attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product type="cloths" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

I used this command

```
xml_split -c /catalog/product[@type='cloths'] products.xml
```

but it reproduces the complete XML document without the XPath filtering.

Comment: And what result are you trying to get? Because that says 'everything under that `product`' and that's everything in your XML. Which elements are you trying to separate out?

Comment: The xml is 400k in size has the `<product type="X">` where X is cloths, electronics, .. etc so this is just a single part of a product type but I want to split this 400k to many chunks based on the type attribute.

Comment: Do you _just_ want the `product` element? And are they unique? (is there only one `product` element of each type?)

Comment: Also: 400k isn't huge. 400G is huge. A 400k XML file will take maybe 4MB of memory, which isn't an insufferable amount, meaning you can do some other tricks (like reparent nodes into new documents)

Comment: Sorry each product type has too many entries `grep -c '<product type="cloths" products.xml   // output :  8039` and it is 400 MB :)

Comment: OK. 4G footprint. Makes it a bit more complicated, because it's actually quite hard to maintain a consistent document without keeping it in memory.

Comment: OK, I think I have a memory consuming solution, that creates multiple documents in memory. I think it _should_ be possible to flush them to disk as you go, but that's a bit more complicated!

Comment: I am trying your code and I'll tell you what I have done, thanks

Comment: `missing target in paste at type.pl line 23.` this what I got in the last code, the first one is working generating files with small chunks while the middle code crash my box memory. Thank you again for your efforts

Comment: Hmm, worked with my sample.  Might be something like a product without a type? Otherwise,  you may need some print statements.

Comment: So could we pass the type as an argument so I could target the category I want instead of all categories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so - if I read you right, you're looking at separating out your product types into separate files.

I'd probably do that like this, using [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub split_product {
    my ( $twig, $product ) = @_;
    open( my $output, '>>', $product->att('type') . ".xml" ) or warn $!;
    print {$output} $product->sprint;
    $twig -> purge; 
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
    twig_handlers => { 'product' => \&split_product }
);
$twig->parsefile('source.xml');
```

This won't preserve XML structure though, it'll just put the 'product' elements into a new file. (And that won't be valid XML if there's multiple products of the same type, either).

OK, so given multiple products of each type, it's necessary to traverse the file. This makes it more complicated, because you can't 'close off' your XML until you know what needs to be in it, which means you need to traverse your tree twice, potentially.

The simpler (memory intensive) way of tackling this problem would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %products;

use XML::Twig;

sub split_product {
    my ( $twig, $product ) = @_;
    my $type = $product->att('type');
    if ( not $products{$type} ) {
        my $new_product = XML::Twig->new;
        $new_product->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('catalogue') );
        $new_product->set_xml_version('1.0');
        $new_product->set_encoding('utf-8');
        $new_product->set_doctype('catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd"');
        $products{$type} = $new_product;
    }
    $product->cut;
    $product->paste( 'last_child', $products{$type}->root );
    $twig->purge;
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
    twig_handlers => { 'product' => \&split_product }
);
$twig->parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );

foreach my $product_type ( keys %products ) {
    open ( my $output, '>', "$product_type.xml" ) or warn $!; 
    print {$output} $products{$product_type}->sprint;
}
```

This will cut it up into separate valid documents, but be warned - it will consume about 10x the size of your XML in memory.

And last, but not least - a (hopefully!) less memory intensive version, that uses [`flush`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm#Flush) and `purge` to dump parsed XML.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %products;
my %product_files;

use XML::Twig;

sub split_product {
    my ( $twig, $product ) = @_;
    my $type = $product->att('type');
    if ( not $products{$type} ) {
        my $new_product = XML::Twig->new;
        $new_product->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('catalogue') );
        $new_product->set_xml_version('1.0');
        $new_product->set_encoding('utf-8');
        $new_product->set_doctype('catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd"');
        $products{$type} = $new_product;
        open( $product_files{$type}, '>', "$type.xml" ) or warn $!;
    }
    $product->cut;
    $product->paste( 'last_child', $products{$type}->root );
    $twig->purge;
    $products{$type}->flush( $product_files{$type} );
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
    twig_handlers => { 'product' => \&split_product }
);
$twig->parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );

foreach my $product_type ( keys %products ) {
    $products{$product_type}->flush( $product_files{$product_type} );
    close( $product_files{$product_type} );
}
```

If you want to just select one particular type, we can either set it within the script:

```
my $target_type = 'cloths';
```

Or read it from `@ARGV` (command line args).

```
my ( $target_type ) = @ARGV;
```

And then either set your 'twig_handler' to:

```
"product[\@type=\"$target_type\"]" => \&split_product
```

Although that will mean purging data from memory happens less often. So instead you can add into the handler:

```
if ( $product -> att('type') eq $target_type ) { 
    $twig -> purge;
    return;
}
```